# How to change layout depending on screen resolution

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have issues with auto layout, when was presenter new iPhone my layout which was created for 5, 5.5, and at the 6.4 inch was locks not so nice.

Example iPhone XS Max:

[image]

iPhone 8:

[image]

So, how i can fix this, and this will locks nice?

Comment: You comment that you're using a table view. You may be better off using a `UIStackView`, constrain its Top and Bottom (to safe area), and set its Distribution to Equal Spacing.

Comment: plz explain how you are adding constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Check your view constraint(bottom) It should be connect with Safe Area not superview

Comment: this view are in the table view, and this connect to the safe area

Comment: What about the green button bottom contraint? How did you set?

Comment: my opinion is't because tableview, i fix to the cell

Answer (score 0):

Form your question what I understand is that you want to distribute space according to screens.

I think you should divide cell layouts on to 3 parts and add controls of that part in to a views[image]

then give all views equal height.

By doing this you will have full screen decided in three parts.

And at the end you can add constraints to controls which we added in view according to you requirements.

Note: Cell main content view height should be equals to screen height.
Hope this helps.